# Mono on MAC OS X El Capitan: LSOpenURLsWithRole

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I have a .NET software which is running on Mono on both Linux and MAC. The software was packed as .app with **Macpack** on Mono 3.6.0 under OSX Lion and created an installer with PackageMaker. It worked fine on all new versions of OSX up until El Capitan which triggers the following error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file .../Applications/MyApp.app
```

I've moved the development files on El Capitan and managed to pack it with **Macpack** from **Mono 4.0.4.4**. It doesn't seem to show that error when using

```
open -a MyApp.app
```

The only problem now is that it doesn't start on double-click. The software is installed in /Applications by the installer. It starts fine from console with **open** command but not on double-click. Is there a way I can see an error or something by emulating the double-click from console ?

PS. Also on El Capitan the only Mono framework that seems to work is the latest 4.0.4.4 or the one designed for El Capitan, 4.2.1. The new location for the binaries are in /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin and this works only if /usr/local/bin exists prior to installation, otherwise mono command won't be recognized.

Thanks

Comment: Re: Mono Versions; That is correct, either 4.0.4.4 or 4.2.1 are the supported versions for El Capitan. The move from /usr/bin to /usr/local/bin is a requirement of El Capitan as no third-party is supposed to modify anything in /usr/bin. The issue with /usr/local/bin not existing before a fresh install is a known issue.

Comment: As far as your launch issue, have you looked in the Console.app? Any errors reported there during a double-click? Might be a perms issue, does the launcher binary within the app bundle have the right permissions and is the app bundle itself flagged as executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no fix yet you can use this temporary fix. After packing with **macpack** open the app folder and go to /Contents/MacOS and edit the last if else from your launch script:

```
MONO_PATH="/usr/bin/mono"

cd "$APP_PATH/Contents/Resources"

if [ "$X11_MODE" -eq "1" ]; then
        open-x11 "$APP_NAME"
else
        if [ -f "/usr/local/bin/mono" ]; then MONO_PATH="/usr/local/bin/mono" ; fi
        "$MONO_PATH" "$ASSEMBLY"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here (El Capitan). Thats how I solved (Mono 4.2.1)

1) Create an empty script and replace the one created by macpack (ex: KeePass.app/Contents/MacOS/KeePass)

2) Use full path for mono and for the exe file

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd) 
/usr/local/bin/mono $DIR/../Resources/KeePass.exe
```

I think thats somehow related to system-integrity-protection (csrutil) but not sure.

Comment: That is a temporary fix that will work on El Capitan only: /usr/local/bin/mono "$ASSEMBLY"  If you want to run in on previous version you got to change mono path to /usr/bin/mono ...

Comment: system-integrity-protection wont allow you to run "which" because its located in /usr/bin .

Comment: Alright, then what can we use instead of `which` to locate mono, because it can be in two different locations based on OSX version.

Comment: if [ -f /usr/local/bin/mono ]; then

Answer (score 1):

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file
>   .../Applications/MyApp.app

Sounds like it might be permissions issue, but -10810 can mean a lot of things and I never have seen a response to that error number that is definitive as to its original (it has been around since PowerPC days). Permissions, external drive access and the actual Launch Services daemons have been pointed to.

- Reboot (or manually kill and respawn those services, including Finder/Spotlight)
- ls -l /Application/YourApp.app and check that is flagged as executable
- ls -l /Application/YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp and check that is flagged as executable
- Open Console.app and retry double-clicking your app and review warnings/errors that are logged.
- ...

**Moving to El Capitan? Then you need Mono version 4.2.x or 4.0.4.4.**

From the Mono mailing list:

> What is the difference between the latest Mono 4.0.4.4 package for Mac
>   and the 4.2.1 El Capitan Preview? The changelog of 4.0.4.4 includes
>   “33585: El Capitan System Integrity Protection support.” so i suppose
>   that the 4.0.4.4 also works on El Capitan?.

Reply from Miguel de Icaza:

> One is based on Mono 4.0 series, with minimal changes just to enable
>   the support on El Capitan; The 4.2 has the same changes, on top of the
>   latest Mono 4.2, available on Alpha and the release candidate.

Ref: http://sushihangover.github.io/osx-10-dot-11-el-capitan-which-mono-version/

Comment: Hey RobertN, This is what I get in the System Log Queries: Oct 17 00:34:16 Daniels-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (MyApp.111072[1451]): Service exited with abnormal code: 127

Comment: Daniels-MBP:sca daniel$ cd /Applications/
Daniels-MBP:Applications daniel$ ls -l MyApp.app/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  5 root  admin  170 Oct 16 13:25 Contents
Daniels-MBP:Applications daniel$ ls -l MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/
total 8
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  1411 Oct 16 13:11 MyApp

Comment: Error 127 is command/file not found; is your launch app (within your app bundle a script?), is it hardcode to find mono in /usr/bin or ...?

Comment: Also since it is Error 127, check to see if some file being accessed has the wrong permissions in your App bundle... Maybe a system file during the ElCap upgrade is flagged wrong, try Disk Utility and wrong Fix Disk Perms on that volume.

Comment: macpack's gen'd script might be the problem, the linking (ln) of mono into the bin directory might be the issue. Delete the mono symbolic link in the bin directory so it can be recreated to find mono correctly.

Comment: From what I can tell in Disk utility the drive looks fine (I'm not a daily osx user). Not sure what else to check.  Thanks for your help

Comment: And by deleting the symbolic link to mono, I mean the one inside the app bundle that the machack launch script creates when it runs (which is a really funky thing to do anyway) Re: Third line up from the bottom of your script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92562/discussion-between-daniel-and-robertn).

Comment: Missed this one (I'm on PST), gotta go, lets try tomorrow if you still need help

Comment: I resumed this at command "which mono" that is not working when using double-click mode but works with open -a app from terminal. Do you know any restrictions on El Capitan that could stop "which" command to run properly ?