# mono macpack under MacOS 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: macos, mono

I have been using mono on a mac for some time.  I use macpack to create a MAC OS application package.  I recently upgraded to OS 10.11 and it seems to not work.  I also upgraded to mono framework 4.2.1.  I get the following log error:

```
10/18/15 11:12:36.216 AM Safari[562]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 100 __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 22
10/18/15 11:12:39.872 AM lsd[301]: LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file at /private/var/db/lsd/com.apple.lsdschemes.plist
10/18/15 11:12:40.016 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (QuoteCourier.203552[1242]) Service exited with abnormal code: 127
```

Comment: Can you expand on when you get the error, does it relate to an lsopenurlswothrole failure? I am assuming it is when you actaully launch your app that has been macpack but that is not really clear in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183502/mono-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan-lsopenurlswithrole/33183838#33183838

Comment: Also did you upgrade your OS-X version or was it a fresh install. Did you install 4.0.4.4/4.2.1 before and after the OS-X upgrade. What does 'which mono' reply with. Is this a new macpack application creation or did it exist before the 10.11 upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the script created by macpack.

Had the same problem using KeePass.

[Ref and code for KeePass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183502/mono-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan-lsopenurlswithrole/33183838#33183838)